# How to use a DataSet in C# Ado .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, dataset

I am creating a database-driven Windows Form Application using Visual Studio 2012.

First of all, I have created a Database, with a table in SQL Server 2012 which has 6 columns and 17 rows.

Then, I added the Database as a DataSet in my Project by going to "Add New Data Source" in the Visual Studio 2012.

Now, in my DataSet Designer, I can see a DataTable is created which contains the columns of my table, and a DataTableAdapter which contains the SQL query to fill the DataTable with my data in the original table in the database.

Which I can view successfully by selecting "Preview Data" option. It shows that all the data is successfully stored in the DataTable.

My question is, how can I use this DataTable (which is already created) to perform operations on the data? All the tutorials I saw shows how to create a new DataSet and then a new DataTable to perform operations on it.

What if I want to use this table? When I use some code which uses this DataTable, it reports an error that it is not present in current context.

I just want to know the code to perform operations on a DataTable which gets generated using "Add a new Data Source" option like Selecting a single row, or record from it.

Comment: Why do you doesn't use Entity Framework? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx

Comment: `When I use some code which uses this DataTable, it reports an error that it is not present in current context.`. Can you explain what are the `some code` that you have already tried?

Comment: Any Code which is performed on a dataTable! I mean the DataTable which is generated using "Add new Data Source" is not detected by my main Form1.cs :3

Comment: Bharadwaj, If possible, can you look into my project using something like teamViewer? P.S. I'm Indian too :P

Comment: I have slow internet connection :( still downloading teamviewer :P. It may take long time :(.

Comment: okay :( http://www.facebook.com/HIMANSHU.AR0RA if you want!